# How to loop through a List of Lists and add each element to a new List

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I loop through every element in a List of Lists and then add these elements to a new List as per the details below:

I have a List of Lists containing Strings as such:

```
List< List<String> > myStringList;
```

How do I loop through each element and then add each individual element to a new List as such:

```
List<String> myNewStringList;
```

Comment: `void main() {
final listA = [
[1, 2, 3],
[5, 6, 7],
[10, 11],
];
final listB = listA.expand((i) => i).toList();
print(listA);
print(listB);
}`

Comment: btw if you `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';` you can even use `myStringList.flattened`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result can be achieved by iterating myNewStringList and its inner list.

```dart
 
 List<List<String> > myStringList;

 List<String> myNewStringList = [];
 
 /// Assuming myStringList has some data in it.
 for(var list in myNewStringList){
   for(var item in list){
      myNewStringList.add(item);
   }  
 }
```

Comment: no need for those loops, just use [flattened](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableIterableExtension/flattened.html)

Answer (score 0):

Took this code from an old project, hope it solves it for you, same as the one from [TheAlphamerc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68449404/how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-lists-and-add-each-element-to-a-new-list#answer-68449452) but prettier.

```
List<String> _plainList(List<List<String>> inputList){
    List<String> _plainList = [];

    for (List<String> l in inputList)
        for (String s in l)
            _plainList.add(s);

    return _plainList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use .forEach method on the  myStringList .